# Display members in group in template

Tags: members, groups

Is there a way to display all the members that belong to a certain group_id inside a template without resorting to the lame and gross profile_themes nonsense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did this recently with the [AC Member List add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ac-member-list).

```
{exp:ac_memberlist group_id="5|6|7"}
  <h2>{screen_name}</h2>
  <li>Username: {username}</li>
  <li>Name: {screen_name}</li>
{/exp:ac_memberlist}
```

Make sure this is outside of any `{exp:channel:entries}` tag. I spent hours with that mistake :)

Answer (score 5):

You will need to use either a custom query

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_members GROUP BY group_id"}
 tags here
{/exp:query}
```

The other option would be to use an add-on such as [Solspace User](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/user/) and their users tag

```
{exp:user:users} 
  content 
{/exp:user:users}
```

Comment: Actually, AC Memberlist is the route to take apparently. Thanks though Justin.

Answer (score 4):

We've done it before, but as we've been using Profile:Edit or Zoo Visitor, we've just used the standard exp:channel:entries tag to do the listing as Member data is transferred into Channel Entries.

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="members"
    dynamic="off"
    status="Open"
    group_id="8"
    limit="50"
}
```

Job done.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that as an option. It's for an established site so it has to use the EE Member data. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old post, but I am posting this answer in case anyone else should stumble upon it.

EE7 (and I think EE6) have exposed all of its member tags, as well as the {exp:member:memberlist} tags so you can build these lists in your own template designs and are not restricted by the "lame and gross profile_themes nonsense".

You can then combine the {exp:member:memberlist} tags with the {exp:member:custom_profile_data} tags to build out flexible member lists based on your own configuration and need, inside of your own site templates.

They have also made the {exp:member:member_search} functions available in the same way, to allow you to create dynamic, sortable lists.

Documentation can be found here:
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/member/memberlist.html